# Exit Try vs Exit Sub

Tags: vb.net, try-catch, exit

I have the following Try statement although when the value that gets written to DB is too large everything after this doesn't run. 
Should i rather use Exit Try instead of Exit Sub?

```
Try

    Dim conn As OracleConnection
    Dim cmdProduction As New OracleCommand
    conn = GetConnect()
    conn.Open()
    cmdProduction.Connection = conn
    cmdProduction.CommandText = "INSERT INTO PRODUCTION (DateTime, Plant, Runhours, Tons, Shift, Sft, Plant_Ord) Values ('" & DateTime & "','FM1-Selox','" & (seloxRuntime / 60) & "','" & seloxTons & "','" & theShift & "','" & sft & "','51')"
    cmdProduction.ExecuteNonQuery()
Catch ex As Exception
    WriteToFile("Production - Production : Database Error : " & ex.Message)
    conn.Close()
    Exit Sub
Finally
    conn.Close()
End Try
```

Comment: Your biggest issue is `Catch ex As Exception`. Don't. Ever. Catch. Exception. It's bad programming. You might as well use `Goto` in your code. Always catch specific exceptions only that you **can** properly handle.

Comment: There's another major issue with this code: `SQL injection` => [Give me parameterized SQL, or give me death](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need either, remove `conn.Close` and `Exit Sub` from the `Catch` and you're good to go. `conn.Close` will be executed from the `Finally`.

```
Try
'
'
'
Catch ex As Exception
    WriteToFile("Production - Production : Database Error : " & ex.Message)
Finally
    conn.Close()
End Try
```

Of course, if your example code is incomplete and actually looks like this:

```
Finally
    conn.Close()
End Try

' More code
```

then either use `Exit Sub`, or move the remaining code into the `Try`.

```
Try
'
'
'
' More code
Catch ex As Exception
    WriteToFile("Production - Production : Database Error : " & ex.Message)
Finally
    conn.Close()
End Try
```

Comment: after that there is more try statements for different plants and different error messages for each plant. So will i then use Exit Sub?

When would i use Exit Try?

Comment: @heinrich: It's slightly unclear what you are asking here but if you **do** want to execute the rest of the code in the sub after this block then you don't need to use anything at all, the execution will drop out of the `Try/Catch/Finally` and continue. If you **don't** want to continue execution after the error then use `Exit Sub`.

Comment: thank you even in my rambles you still manage to explain it perfectly.